# Changing Eclipse run time environment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer

A Java RunTime Environment(JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run MemoryAnalyzer. No Java virtual mchine was found after searching the following locations: C:\Documents and Settings......

***My question is how do I change the path of the JRE or JDK?***

Note *I have eclipse working completely fine.*

Answer (score 8):

```
Window--Preferences---Java-->Installed JREs
```

There you can add JRE path.

Comment: On ADD JRE. I selected standard vm and on JRE home: I selected the path of the memory analyzer on "JRE home" and then I have this error on the top stating "Target is not a JDK Root. Java executable was not found". I am sorry if I did something wrong I am not really familiar with JREs and JDKs.

Comment: Dont go till JRE, just select java folder. For example if java is at c:myfolder\java\jre. Just select till c:\myfolder\java

Comment: Oh okay I get it now the purpose of it was to find the JRE inside a Java file. I still don't get though is that Memory analyzer which is not connected to eclipse yet is searching for the JRE in another folder how do I change that one? Sorry maybe I should have mentioned that it wasn't connected to eclipse yet.

Comment: Reason for this comment is because I got this Error stating that "Java Runtime Environment is already in use". I assume that onclick on the memory analyzer folder I could change something.

Comment: What is Memory Analyzer? Is it eclipse plugin (or) separate application? Not sure on what you are struggling with.

Comment: I believe it's an eclipse plugin.

Comment: It seems it is specific to this plugin configuration than eclipse configuration. I am sorry! I have never worked on this plugin. But some places to look are, Window--Preference and see if any name with Memory analyzer exists on left side, if so check any configuration can be done there.

Comment: Okay thanks for trying, I will post out an answer as soon as I am done for everyone else and change the title name.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the your project. You can see the java build path . On that select configure build path. You can see the window, there click on add external JAR.